# Segmentation faul even with memory allocation of 2d array

Tags: c, file, segmentation-fault, dynamic-memory-allocation

I'm trying to read a file that contains a five letter word on each line for 12972 lines. I'm not sure why I'm getting this error even with freeing storage.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    FILE *file;
    file = fopen("words.txt", "r");                                                  // Opens file

    char** gssArr = (char**)malloc(12972 * sizeof(char*));       // Allocates memory for 2d array

    for(int i = 0; i < 12972; i++)
    {
        gssArr[i] = (char*)malloc(5 * sizeof(char));
    }

    char word[6];                                    // Current word being looked at from file
    int current = 0;                                    // Used for indexing x coordinate of 2d array
    while(fgets(word,6,file) != NULL)   // Not at end of file
    {
        if(word[0] != '\n')                  // Not at end of line
        {
            for(int j = 0; j < 5; j++)           // Loops through all 5 letters in word, adding them to gssArr
            {
                gssArr[current][j] = word[j];
            }
        }
        current++;                                  // Index increase by 1
    }
    fclose(file);                         // Close file, free memory
    free(gssArr);
```

Comment: Where do you get the segmentation fault?

Comment: Freeing memory doesn't prevent segmentation fault. It prevents memory leaks. You have a memory leak because you never free all the `gssArr[i]`.

Comment: looks like you are using a C++ compiler, you should not cast the return value of malloc

Comment: @AndersK You have it backwards. You need the cast with C++, you don't need it with C.

Comment: personally i would be a bit more generous when reading a line from the file instead of exactly 6 chars. use a 128 byte buffer or something, then retrieve what you need.

Comment: What's the point of this code? You read the lines into the array, but then you immediately free the array.

Comment: And if they're 5 character words on each line, `word` needs to be at least `word[7]`. You need a byte for the newline and another for the null terminator.

Comment: @barmar umm that is what i wrote? he should compile it as C code, not C++ code

Comment: @AndersK You're assuming he used the cast because the compiler complained. We see lots of people using it just because that's what they've been taught or saw in other code.

Comment: @barmar a C compiler would accept a malloc without a cast.

Comment: @AndersK I know. That's why I said it's required in C++, not in C. The fact that he wrote something that's needed in C++ doesn't mean he's using a C++ compiler.

Comment: somebody is writing a wordle app

Comment: Unrelated to the issue, you could also do it in one allocation using a pointer to an array.

Comment: I'm sorry for the vagueness. It's in C btw. 
This is just a snippet of the code with some things moved around so it makes sense. I'm not gonna upload 300 lines of stuff you dont need.
Gold star for the person who knew it was wordle related. I'm making a program to take all the words and find their relations to find the best opening word right now. Making a game solver from their. I saw someone comment I never stopped count++ so thanks for that.

Answer (score 1):

FYI - your reader loop - you may want to make sure that your current index is not going beyond 12971.

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is here:

```
current++;
```

**Why?**

Because it's done even when you are at the end of the line.
One solution is to move it inside the `if` statement but instead I'll recommend that you use `fgets` with a much larger buffer.

**Details**

If every line holds a five letter word then

```
fgets(word,6,file)
```

will read the five letters and zero terminate it. Then the next `fgets` will just read the "newline". Still you increment the index counter and in the end, you write outside allocated memory.

Try

```
while(fgets(word,6,file) != NULL)   // Not at end of file
{
    printf("current=%d\n", current);
```

and you see the problem.